# Submit Handler not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The code I am using below is validating correctly but not submitting when fields are valid:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#verifyformDesktop").validate({
   errorContainer: "#messageBox1, #messageBox2",
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
   wrapper: "li", debug:true,
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     form.submit();
   }
 })
});
</script>

<form name="verifyformDesktop" id="verifyformDesktop" action="php/verify.php" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="ENTER">
```

Maybe the submitHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `debug: true,` from your `.validate()` options.

It's only used for testing and blocks the `submit`.

> **debug:** Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted...

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/FHAV2/

You also do not need to declare a `submitHandler:` function...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

... because that's simply the default plugin behavior when you leave it out.

However, if you need to do other things, then it is correct...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do some other stuff before submit
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I guess i looked it over since i didnt have it on a new line.

Comment: @Hector, I didn't even notice it myself until I put the jsFiddle together.  Please also see my edit.