# Why does jQuery Validate Adds Error to a Valid Field?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm working on a form having several fields and when "onblur" occurs jquery validate is adding the error class/label to a valid field.

This is my form html

```
<div id="diaAddCustomer" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color: #fff; width: 650px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Customer</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmAddCustomer" name="frmAddCustomer" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" id="addCustomerPersonID" name="addCustomerPersonID" value="">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerName">Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerName" name="addCustomerName" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4>Billing Address</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerAdd1">Address:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerAdd1" name="addCustomerAdd1" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerAdd2"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerAdd2" name="addCustomerAdd2" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerCity">City:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerCity" name="addCustomerCity" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerState">State:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerState" name="addCustomerState" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="addCustomerZip">Zip:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerZip" name="addCustomerZip" value="" onkeyup="valNumber($(this))">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerPhone">Phone:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerPhone" name="addCustomerPhone" onkeyup="valNumber($(this))" onblur="formatPhone($(this))" onfocus="removePhoneFormat($(this))" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="addCustomerPhoneType">Type:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerPhonetype" name="addCustomerPhoneType">
                        <option value=""> Please Select...</option>
                        <option value="cell"> Cell</option>
                        <option value="fax"> Fax</option>
                        <option value="phone"> Phone</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerEmail">Email:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerEmail" name="addCustomerEmail" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4>Shipping Address <span style="font-size: 10pt;"><input type="checkbox" id="ckbSameShip" ng-click="setShipAddress()"> Same As Billing</span></h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipAdd1">Address:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipAdd1" name="addCustomerShipAdd1" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipAdd2"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipAdd2" name="addCustomerShipAdd2" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipCity">City:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipCity" name="addCustomerShipCity" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipState">State:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipState" name="addCustomerShipState" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipZip">Zip:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipZip" name="addCustomerShipZip" value="" onkeyup="valNumber($(this))">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipPhone">Phone:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipPhone" name="addCustomerShipPhone" onkeyup="valNumber($(this))" onblur="formatPhone($(this))" onfocus="removePhoneFormat($(this))" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="addCustomerShipPhoneType">Type:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="addCustomerShipPhonetype" name="addCustomerShipPhoneType">
                        <option value=""> Please Select...</option>
                        <option value="cell"> Cell</option>
                        <option value="fax"> Fax</option>
                        <option value="phone"> Phone</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Customer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my validation script

```
$scope.openAddCustomerWdw = function(pID){
        $("#diaAddCustomer").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
            $("#addCustomerPersonID").val(pID);
            $("#addCustomerName").val("");
            $("#addCustomerAdd1").val("");
            $("#addCustomerAdd2").val("");
            $("#addCustomerCity").val("");
            $("#addCustomerState").val("");
            $("#addCustomerZip").val("");
            $("#addCustomerPhone").val("");
            $("#addCustomerPhoneType").val("");
            $("#addCustomerEmail").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipAdd1").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipAdd2").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipCity").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipState").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipZip").val("");
            $("#addCusomterShipPhone").val("");
            $("#addCustomerShipPhoneType").val("");
            $("#addCustomerName").select();
        });
        $("#diaAddCustomer").modal("show");
        $("#frmAddCustomer").validate({
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                addCustomerName: { required: true },
                addCustomerAdd1: { required: true },
                addCustomerCity: { required: true },
                addCustomerState: { required: true },
                addCustomerZip: { required: true },
                addCustomerPhone: { required: true, phoneUS: true },
                addCustomerPhoneType: { required: true },
                addCustomerEmail: { required: function(){
                    return $("#addCustomerEmail").length > 0;
                }, email: true },
                addCustomerShipAdd1: { required: true },
                addCustomerShipCity: { required: true },
                addCustomerShipZip: { required: true },
                addCustomerShipPhone: { required: true, phoneUS: true },
                addCustomerShipPhoneType: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                addCustomerName: { required: "Name is Required" },
                addCustomerAdd1: { required: "Address is Required" },
                addCustomerCity: { required: "City is Required" },
                addCustomerState: { required: "State is Required" },
                addCustomerZip: { required: "Zip Code is Required" },
                addCustomerPhone: { required: "Valid Phone Required", phoneUS: "Valid Phone Required" },
                addCustomerPhoneType: { required: "Phone Type Required" },
                addCustomerEmail: { required: "Valid Email Required", email: "Valid Email Required" },
                addCustomerShipAdd1: { required: "Address is Required" },
                addCustomerShipCity: { required: "City is Required" },
                addCustomerShipState: { required: "State is Required" },
                addCustomerShipZip: { required: "Zip Code is Required" },
                addCustomerShipPhone: { required: "Valid Phone Required", phoneUS: "Valid Phone Required" },
                addCustomerShipPhoneType: { required: "Phone Type is Required" }
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "success"){

                } else {

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

When the form opens the html is as shown above without the jquery label/error class being applied. When entering text in any of the fields except the second address field, the jquery label/error class is applied when onblur occurs. It is an empty label but causes the form fields to drop down for the appended label.

This is what the form looks like when opened

[image: Form when opened]

This is the form after data has been entered

[image: Form after data entered]

I realize jquery validate does form validation on the blur event, os that part I understand working correctly. The problem is the appended error elements in a valid field and the result causing the form to expand in height and no information being provided to what is happening.

I've tried using debug: true, viewing the console window and trying to trace this error in different ways, unfortunately nothing seems to give me any additional error information to work from.

Help in pointing me in the right direction where the error is in code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [The code you posted does not show the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/d0n5L8qj/).  Please construct a more complete demo.

Comment: @Sparky I agree and understand what you are saying and had I not found the problem within the code posted here I would have opened my development environment for you to see more details about what is happening. The problem resolves to be my error in not seeing "success: function(data)" where it should have been "submitHandler: function(data)". Making this fix as described in my answer resolved the issue of those validation fields taking up "space" rather than the expected result of no space as was the case with all forms on this page. Thanks, you did push me to look closer finding the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does jQuery Validate Adds Error to a Valid Field?

It does not.  The plugin dynamically creates *empty* `label` elements for containing any future validation error messages.  Then as validation errors occur, the `label` elements are populated and *toggled* as needed.

> The problem is the appended error elements in a valid field and the result causing the form to expand in height and no information being provided to what is happening.

The `debug` option is only there to point out your various possible syntax errors within the `.validate()` method.  However, your problem is caused by your HTML and/or CSS, therefore, there is no way for this plugin to know about the issue.

As you can see by this demo, your jQuery Validate code has nothing to do with your issue as the layout is totally unaffected by the hidden/empty `label` elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/d0n5L8qj/

In the thousands of questions about jQuery Validate posted here, I have never seen anyone report this scenario.  Normally an empty or hidden element would take up zero space in the layout.  For some totally unknown reason (*you have not shown enough code*) your particular layout is being affected by these empty hidden elements. You'll need to inspect your live DOM and/or your CSS to find the root cause about why these empty `label` elements are taking up space.  Otherwise, you'll have to [create a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that **reproduces the issue** so we can inspect the DOM and/or CSS.

---

**EDIT**:

From [the OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36145466/594235):

> *I don't know how or why making this correction in my code changed the validation fields to no longer take up space as shown in my original post, but making this revision did stop this problem from happening.*

I should not have assumed this was intentional...

```
success: function(data){
    if(data == "success"){

    } else {

    }
}
```

I thought there was more code here and the OP simply removed it for posting.  However, I should not have made this assumption as the `success` option is what's showing the empty `label` elements... they are empty because the `success` function is not populating them with anything.

See [documentation for explanation of how `success` caused the issue](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success):

> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If a String is given, it is added as a class to the label. **If a Function is given, it is called with the label** (as a jQuery object) and the validated input (as a DOM element). The label can be used to add a text like "ok!".

As far as the OP's answer where he simply changed the word `success` into `submitHandler`...

```
submitHandler: function(data){
    if(data == "success"){

    } else {

    }
}
```

This resolves the issue only because he's removed the `success` option.  Changing into `submitHandler` seems totally unnecessary as now the `submitHandler` is being over-written by code that looks like nonsense.

By default, the plugin will submit to the form's `action` attribute URL.  You can optionally use the `submitHandler` to over-ride such as submission via ajax.   Otherwise the `data` argument would represent the `form` object and the conditional makes no sense since `data` will NEVER equal `"success"`... also, in case it's not obvious, there's no point to having an empty conditional statement.

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    form.submit();  // <-default
}
```

Otherwise...

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    // ajax code
    return false;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367008/594235) for more info.

---

**EDIT 2**:

Yes, I realize the argument for the `submitHandler` can be represented by any arbitrary word.  However, the sole argument for this function will always represent the `form` object even if you rename it as `data`.

See the following demo.  Make sure the form is filled out correctly, hit submit, and look at the console's log...

http://jsfiddle.net/8rhmfwtL/

Comment: "Changing into submitHandler is totally unnecessary..." This is another assumption... I do have purpose with not using the action on the form control when submitting the form... This is sudo from the total application it resided in... It is actual code, but not all elements of the code such as AngularJS controllers, services etc. Further assumption is in my needed to create a custom success handler where to me this would be more useless than overriding the submitHandler.

Comment: @aallord, the only information I had is the information you posted when you came here seeking help, and then later expressed confusion about why moving the `success` function into the `submitHandler` function suddenly makes things work properly.  In any case, `if (data == "success")` will do absolutely nothing within the `submitHandler` since the function's sole argument will never be equal to `"success"`.

Answer (score 0):

This evening I stumbled upon the solution even though I'm unable to fully explain why it cause the problem above. The problem was with the validation code. As posted above

```
$("#frmAddCustomer").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            addCustomerName: { required: true },
            addCustomerAdd1: { required: true },
            addCustomerCity: { required: true },
            addCustomerState: { required: true },
            addCustomerZip: { required: true },
            addCustomerPhone: { required: true, phoneUS: true },
            addCustomerPhoneType: { required: true },
            addCustomerEmail: { required: function(){
                return $("#addCustomerEmail").length > 0;
            }, email: true },
            addCustomerShipAdd1: { required: true },
            addCustomerShipCity: { required: true },
            addCustomerShipZip: { required: true },
            addCustomerShipPhone: { required: true, phoneUS: true },
            addCustomerShipPhoneType: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            addCustomerName: { required: "Name is Required" },
            addCustomerAdd1: { required: "Address is Required" },
            addCustomerCity: { required: "City is Required" },
            addCustomerState: { required: "State is Required" },
            addCustomerZip: { required: "Zip Code is Required" },
            addCustomerPhone: { required: "Valid Phone Required", phoneUS: "Valid Phone Required" },
            addCustomerPhoneType: { required: "Phone Type Required" },
            addCustomerEmail: { required: "Valid Email Required", email: "Valid Email Required" },
            addCustomerShipAdd1: { required: "Address is Required" },
            addCustomerShipCity: { required: "City is Required" },
            addCustomerShipState: { required: "State is Required" },
            addCustomerShipZip: { required: "Zip Code is Required" },
            addCustomerShipPhone: { required: "Valid Phone Required", phoneUS: "Valid Phone Required" },
            addCustomerShipPhoneType: { required: "Phone Type is Required" }
        },
        **success: function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
            } else {
            }
        }**
    })
```

The bolded "success: function(data)" should be

```
submitHandler: function(data){
   if(data == "success"){
   } else {
   }
}
```

I don't know how or why making this correction in my code changed the validation fields to no longer take up space as shown in my original post, but making this revision did stop this problem from happening.

I was unable to find this problem out there after hours of searching and as commented by @Sparky, in thousands of JQuery Validate questions they had never seen this situation posted here. I was also unable to find logical reasoning how/why this would cause the problem posted here.

Comment: As per documentation, the `success` function is used for showing the error message elements when the field passes validation.  Instead of changing `success` into `submitHandler`, you should have just removed it entirely.   Why did you have this function in the first place, especially when the conditional is empty?... I assumed you knew what it was doing and simply abbreviated your code for posting.  Please see:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success

Comment: As far as changing it into the `submitHandler`, you should realize this makes no sense at all.   The `submitHandler` is just the function that controls how/where the submission takes place.    The only argument that's passed into `submitHandler` is `form` which represents the `form` object... not the `data`, nor will this object ever match `"success"`, so the empty conditional statement within is also useless.

Comment: The 'form' is an object and can be represented with 'data' or any other variable into the function. Like a submitHandler: function(data) Might not be tagged as data for whatever reason based on return results the programmer is representing... The conditional is empty because prior to writing it I ran into the error. Better to solve bugs prior to completing submit processing, agreed? The conditional actually will land in the success of an ajax call.

Comment: Agreed, the function's sole argument can be represented by any arbitrary word that you choose.  However, in this case, the argument represents the `form` *object* and will never be equal to `"success"`.   See console log:  http://jsfiddle.net/8rhmfwtL/

Answer (score -1):

You might try to add 
`onfocusout: false` in validator. like

```
$("#frmAddCustomer").validate({
        debug: true,
        onfocusout: false,
        ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would be a band aide and not actually solve the problem I'm experiencing as jquery validate should validate when the onblur (onfocusout) occurs to keep users interactively informed of invalid data input.